# Can't submit my app to Apple's App Store

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a problem submitting my app to the App Store. I already sent a mail to the Apple support but they don't help in questions about the App Store.
First of all, I would like to point out that I use a screen reader and it is difficult for me to post graphical representations. But I try to describe my problem as accurately as possible.

I signed and uploaded my app via Xcode. That worked without any problems.
I logged into iTunes Connect and clicked the "My Apps" link. Here I click on "iOS 1.0 in preparation for submission". It appears my prepared or still from the test phase originating App Store entry.
In the form I have supplemented the information still needed, such as the payment model, age rating, etc.
Then I click on the "Submit for review" button at the top and I get the message: "At least one error has occurred on the page.". Unfortunately, there's no information what's wrong.

However, I suspect that the cause lies with the screenshots. The form says: "0 of 3 app previews, 0 of 10 screenshots". So apparently missing the necessary screenshots.
The graphics I have already created with the simulator, one in the resolution 2048x2732 and two in the resolution 1242x2208 and all in PNG format.
In the section "App previews and screenshots" I now click on "Select files". If I select one of my PNG files from my hard drive, I get the following message: "At least one screenshot has wrong dimensions."
I can not get any further because I can not explain what goes wrong here ...

What I already did: I clicked on the link "Media Management".
Here I have added my two smaller screenshots for the iPhone with 5.5" display, which went smoothly and it is displayed correctly "2 of 10 screenshots".
I've added my larger screenshot for the iPad with 12.9" display and it is displayed correctly "1 of 10 screnshots".
Then I click on the "Save" button at the top of the page. However, this seems to have no effect on the App Store entry. I'm at a loss!

Comment: Did you see where "Screenshots must be in the JPG or PNG format, and in the RGB colorspace."?